# C# SQL query not producing data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a section of code in my program that is supposed to pull the most recent time for a batch at a specific event. All I'm getting however is a blank result. I know there's data in the table for the batch in question and SQL Profiler shows it is being executed.

```
 public void UpdateBeginStir()
    {
        string beginStir = null;
        string connectionString = "(Omitted)";
        string commandLine = "SELECT MAX(Event_Time) AS Time " +
                             "FROM dbo.Custom_EventLog " +
                             "WHERE Container_ID = @LOTNUMBR " +
                             "AND Event_ID = 1 " +
                             "GROUP BY BadgeNo, Container_ID, Event_ID";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandLine, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@LOTNUMBR", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = TextBoxLot.Text;
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    beginStir = reader["Time"] as string;
                    break;
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(beginStir, "test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        LabelBeginStir.Content = beginStir;
    }
```

Comment: If you execute the query from SSMS, does it return results?

Comment: so when you execute "SELECT MAX(Event_Time) AS Time 
                             FROM dbo.Custom_EventLog 
                             WHERE Container_ID = 'whatever LOTNUMBR is'
                             AND Event_ID = 1 
                             GROUP BY BadgeNo, Container_ID, Event_ID" , it gives the expected result? What is the value of TextBoxLot.Text?

Comment: When I execute the query in SSMS, I get the expected result of the most recent time. When I run it in the code, I get a blank result as in the message box is blank.

Comment: If you only expect 1 result with 1 value, I'd just `beginStir = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;` and simplify to `command.Parameters.AdWithValue("@LOTNUMBR", TextBoxLot.Text);` while @NemanjaPerovic's answer will likely fix your issue and explains why it doesn't work as it is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SqlDbType.NChar will pad right with blank spaces up to 50 characters, and Container_ID won't match. Use SqlDbType.NVarChar instead

UPDATE: the correct answer ended up being

```
beginStir = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Time"]).ToString();
```

Comment: Good catch... If this is the reason, that's great! @Ryan Fauser. But shouldn't `LOTNUMBR` be an `int` or at least a `number`? Assuming `Container_ID` is an int.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Great point. Also, Filburt made a valid point. There are a few things to improve in this code.

Comment: I get "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" on the Convert.ToInt32 line. I query the lot number in other parts of the program and it works just fine. Could it be something with how I'm entering the Event_ID?

Comment: What is the TextBoxLot.Text (container_ID)? Is it an integer? Also, does my original suggestion of changing NChar to NVarChar solve the issue?

Comment: Container_ID is a NChar on the SQL table. It's a series of numbers like 17080387-002. The original suggestion did not work either.

Comment: Thanks. OK, so it's not a number, it has a hyphen. And since it's a NChar, it will be padded too, as will the parameter. The execute scalar will not work, because you could get multiple results, one per GROUP. I've removed that option from my answer, no point having it there

Comment: I imagine that when you run your query in ssms you get multiple results (based on the grouping). Is there any BadgeNo for which all values of time are null (for container_id = '17080387-002' and event_id = 1)?

Comment: No, BadgeNo, Container_ID, and Event_ID will always not be null in the table.

Comment: OK, the question was - is Time ever null. Also, if Time is declared as  DateTime in the database, try to change "as string" to Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Time"]).ToString() and see if that works. If it does not, please update the question with the structure of the table and some sample values. Thanks

Comment: @NemanjaPerovic Sorry for the confusion, Event_Time is also never null in the table. Your last suggestion worked, thank you.